# How to find the correct path for my CSS link using PHP with a public folder

Tags: php, html, css

As I'm developing my website, I also do some small projects that I would put into my website.
I'd like to have my project section that link to my project. I want each project to have it's own CSS file so that I don't have one that would be very huge. So here's my problem, I have some issue finding the right path to link my css.

Since I use PHP, I have a public folder with the main index.php used as a simple router.
Here's my architecture :

```
|img\
|-- some images
|public\ (docroot)
|--index.php
|--js\
|----index.js
|--style\
|----partials\
|-------_projet.scss
|----main.scss (with @import 'partials/projet')
|----main.css
|templates\
|--projet\
|----files for the project
|--all my templates like header.php, footer.php...
```

Here's index.php in public/ :

```
<?php
require "../vendor/autoload.php";

$required = null;
$projet = null;
$title = 'KumaTeK';
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

switch($uri) {
    case '/' :
        $required = '../templates/home.php';
        break;
    case '/projets/projet1' :
        $projet = '../templates/projet1/index.php';
        $title = 'Projet1';
        break;
    default :
        $required = '../templates/404.php';
        break;
}


if ($required) {
    require '../templates/header.php';
    require $required;
    require '../templates/footer.php';
}

?>
```

In my header.php I have :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
```

Which works on home.php (or '/' for the route).
But when I go to /projets/projet1, I have the HTML without CSS.

I'd like to know if there is a technique to find the correct path or if I'm doing something wrong.
(I have also an issue with path for images.)

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/main.css">` this will import the style relative to the root directory.

Comment: Yes, I know. As I said, it works for my home page which has the route '/'. But it's still in the index.php in the public folder which is the root folder, well I mean when I launch my php server I use "php -S localhost:xxxx -t public".

Comment: Are you sure you added the `/` ahead of `style/...`?

Comment: Yay ! it works ! very simple. Thank you very much ! Still have some issue with images but I'll find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's written in comment you must write :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/main.css">
```

Which is different that

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
```

In the first case, the url will be always relative to your domain name, that means that even if your url is `http://localhost/projets/projet1`, the css url will be `http://localhost/style/main.css` (it's not relative to your current url).

In the second case, the css url will be relative to your current url, that means that even if your url is `http://localhost/projets/projet1`, the css url will be `http://localhost/projets/projet1/style/main.css` (it's relative to your current url).

Comment: Thank you for this very instructive answer!